# Why should 3-Opt be used over 2-opt for solving TSP?

Tags: traveling-salesman

I know the working of 2-opt and 3-opt local search algorithm. But I could not find any example where solution improvement is not possible using 2-opt but 3-opt. I am looking for a proper explanation along with diagrams where TSP solution is not improved by 2-opt but 3-Opt can improve it.